# MySQL connections not closing

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I have a web application running on Tomcat7 that connects to MySQL 5.5.

I have two servers running the identical code:

- Ubuntu
- Red Hat

The Ubuntu one runs fine maintaining a steady 8-16 connections, but the Red Hat one leaks connections and the connection count grows, never going down.  The server eventually resets ~152 connections.

The code to close the connection is getting called:

```
try {
    conn.close();           
} catch (SQLException e) {
    exceptionController.logException(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "finalize Db", e.getMessage(), false);
}finally{
    conn = null;
}
```

All connections to MySQL are from this app.

Why the difference in behavior?  **Are there configuration settings that I should be considering - like closing sleeping connections setting**?

**Ubuntu Server Status:**

[image]

**Red Hat Server Status:**

[image: MySQLWorkbench Server Status Screen]

**Partial screen of the connection list:**
[image: MySQLWorkbench Server Connection List]

I found this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/how-long-is-too-long-for-mysql-connections-to-sleep), which appears to have slowed o/s connections, but they still are creeping up.

**EDIT**

Research is pointing to the connections not closing properly.  Why would the connections close in one environment but not another?

I have edited `my.cnf` with the following setting:

```
wait_timeout=30
```

However, client connections are sleeping and never getting killed.  The server has been restarted with the new setting in place.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: What does `show full processlist ` show

Comment: @exussum - Would you please explain?  Do you mean Client connections list?  If so, all the connections are from the web app on both servers.

Comment: It will show what's making the connections and what's happening on them. Run that in mysql

Comment: @exussum  They are sleeping.

Comment: @AndroidAddict what is the name of this app that lets you vizualize the open connections

Comment: @meda  MySQLWorkbench

Comment: really I have it, I didnt know you can do that cool

Comment: @meda Yes - really cool - can be found right under server status.

Comment: @AndroidAddict which language is this coded in you didnt put a tag

Comment: Given the servers that you mention, I would tend to guess that the Ubuntu server has been running for some time now (a development server, perhaps) and the Red Hat server is a production server to which you are trying to transition... Could it be that the Redhat server is receiving a very large bulk of data at once on startup (some initialization or synchronization task, for example), but that the operation eventually fail and the transaction has to be rollbacked? That's only speculation, here...

Comment: @jwatkins You're assumption on dev/prod is correct.  But, there is no heavy load that I am aware of that is or even should be hitting the server.  The only thing that makes sense to me is a configuration issue.  Any guidance is appreciated.  :^)  It really appears the connections on Red Hat instance are not closing as expected.

Comment: What if you do a "KILL PROCESS <id>" on the MySQL Server? Are those connections being closed correctly? What I mean by this is that it is possible that a connection has been closed correctly by your application, but that the MySQL server is keeping them in a kind of transient state while transactions are being rollbacked and/or locks are being freed...  If it is so, then "KILL PROCESS <connection id>" will appears to have no effect...

Comment: @jwatkins I am running transactions.  That may explain the sleep, however, commits and rollbacks are being performed respectively.  I will give your suggestion a go and let you know - thanks!

Comment: Another possibility is that your datasource on the RedHat server is pooled, with a very high maximum connections count. Then, closing the connection in your code would actually only release the connection back to the pool, but not disconnect from the MySQL server. However, the number of open connections should stabilize somewhere around the maximum number of concurrent connections that you are receiving to your server, which appears not to be the case, and which is why I did not came up with this scenario before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.  XP on [SO Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81056/mysql-wait-timeout-setting-ignored/81066#81066).

RedHat has its own mysql folders:

```
[root@localhost ~]# locate my.cnf
/etc/my.cnf
/opt/rh/mysql55/root/etc/my.cnf
```

It was a configuration issue and **my config file was not being used!**